# How fast can a driver accelerate without spilling his coffee?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

A person is driving  a car with a cup of coffee in his cup holder. The cup is cylindrical with a diameter of 5cm and is filled up to 1 cm from the rim.

How much may the driver accelerate or decelerate on a level road so that he won't spill any coffee.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem and what blockers have you encountered?

Comment: Among other things, you appear to have ignored the size of the cup.  I hearby define its height as 1cm.  The cup is empty and will never spill.

Comment: You have given insufficient information to answer your question.  The physics of "sloshing" also requires information about the depth of the liquid in the container.  That is because the surface tension plays a role in this phenomenon.  For example, suppose the depth is only 1mm.  One would need much greater acceleration in order to overcome surface tension and spill out than would be the case if the depth were 10 cm.  I will venture a guess that this question is more complex than you realize.

Comment: @LewisMiller: maybe but it appears you're needlessly complexifying. I won't fully answer because the question will be put on hold but it's easy to show that in a roomy container and under *constant acceleration* $a$ the liquid's surface is inclined to the horizontal by $\theta$, so that $\tan\theta=\frac{a}{g}$.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This is all the information I was given.

Comment: if $\theta$ is the angle of inclination of the free surface of coffee with horizontal at the maximum   acceleration $a$ when the coffee is just about to spill out, then a relation can be easily established $$\tan\theta=\frac{a}{g}$$ $$\frac{1}{5/2}=\frac{a}{9.81}\ \ \ \ \implies a=??$$

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think acceleration a=(g/5).First,you draw a right angled triangle such that the
hypotenuse makes an angle A with the horizontal.This represents the angle at which
the surface of the liquid is inclined to the horizontal.Now when the coffee is just about to spill,the perpendicular of this right angled triangle=1cm and base=
5 cm(the diameter of the cylindrical cup).Thus,tan A=(1/5),and we know,tan A=(a/g).
Hence,we get:-

a/g=tan A=(1/5).=>a=(g/5).

Comment: What is your source for the claim that the liquid will form a tilted surface like that, and that the acceleration counteracts gravity that way?  Your formula looks more applicable to finding the center of force on a rigid object

Comment: The driver is driving on a level road with constant